# Cakephp media() not allowing for variable link.. resulting in preg_match() error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

USING CAKEPHP 4

Basically, I am using paginate to show video posts that have been uploaded to a site. I am able to get for each video:

- title
- description
- user id & user name

(on view page)
These are all done with:

```
<?php foreach ($video as $vid): ?>
            <tr id="vidbox">
                <td>
                    <p><?= $this->Html->link(__(h($vid->user->username)), ['controller'=>'Users','action' => 'view', $vid->user->id]); ?></p>
                    <u><h2><?= ($vid->title) ?></h2></u>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>Desc:<?= h($vid->description) ?></p>
                </td>
```

however when i try to use media() and access in the same way, i am getting a preg_match() error that either tells me that parameter 2 should be a string, or that parameter 2 must be an array.
Here is the code i am trying...

```
 <td>
     <?php echo $this->Html->media($vid->link);?>
 </td>
```

The 'link' is saved into the database when the video is uploaded - it saves the location of the file and its name.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `debug($vid->link);` give you?

Comment: @GregSchmidt it comes up with the video name.

Comment: @GregSchmidt
```
ROOT/templates/Home/index.php (line 56)
'testvido.mp4'
```
I have been adding path infront of the video name in media(), e.g media('/vid/'.$vid->link), doesnt work